# Как передать данные с сервера на клиентскую часть

Tags: javascript, node.js

Создаю чат, с помощью метода пост отправляю данные с формы на сервер, и затем перенаправляю на страницу чата. У меня есть блок на странице, в котором должно быть имя пользователя, введенное на странице регистрации, как мне отобразить туда данные полученные с сервера? В данный момент все это делаю через локальное хранилище.

Вот как получаю данные на сервере с формы (index.js):

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (
    request,
    response
) {
    if (!request.body)
        return response.sendStatus(400);
    response.redirect("client/chat.html");
    console.log(request.body.Username);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => { 
....
```

Вот как это происходит на данный момент:
register.js

```
const FORM = document.querySelector(".FORM");
const INPUT = document.querySelector(".INPUT");

FORM.addEventListener('submit', (Event) => {
    Event.preventDefault();
    if (INPUT.value) {
        let name = INPUT.value;
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
        Event.target.reset();
    }
});
```

main.js

```
const userName = localStorage.getItem('name');
nameBlock.innerHTML = userName;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вставлял с помощью innertHTML данные полученные с сервера

Answer (score 0):

Я использую [EJS](https://ejs.co/). Выглядит это примерно так:

Сервер:

```js
app.set('views', PATH.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (
    request,
    response
) {
    if (!request.body)
        return response.sendStatus(400);
    response.redirect("views/chat.ejs", {user_name: request.body.Username});
    console.log(request.body.Username);
});
```

Клиент (views/chat.ejs)

```html
<p><%= user_name %></p>

<script>
  var name = '<%= user_name %>';
</script>
```